# .net C# Simply custom plain text encryption & decryption bug

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, encryption

As a young software developer iv always wanted to make a plain text encryption and this is my start to hopefully something wayy bigger.

But this simple encryption turns lowercase and uppercase letters into certain static number with a . after to represent the end of the letter, But with the decryption its the same thing but flipped but for some reason it don't work as seen below.

Plain Text Input: abcd
Encrypted Text Output: 01.10.1.11.
Decrypted Text Output: abc1c

Here is the Encryption and Decryption code block below.

```
public static string CCENC(string plainText)
{
            // Encrypt Lowercase and Captial Letters
    if (plainText.Contains("a")) { string num = plainText.Replace("a", "01."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("A")) { string num = plainText.Replace("A", "11010."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("b")) { string num = plainText.Replace("b", "10."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("B")) { string num = plainText.Replace("B", "110."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("c")) { string num = plainText.Replace("c", "1."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("C")) { string num = plainText.Replace("C", "0."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("d")) { string num = plainText.Replace("d", "11."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("D")) { string num = plainText.Replace("D", "00."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("e")) { string num = plainText.Replace("e", "010."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("E")) { string num = plainText.Replace("E", "001."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("f")) { string num = plainText.Replace("f", "1100."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("F")) { string num = plainText.Replace("F", "0011."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("g")) { string num = plainText.Replace("g", "00001."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("G")) { string num = plainText.Replace("G", "01010."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("h")) { string num = plainText.Replace("h", "110011."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("H")) { string num = plainText.Replace("H", "110110."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("i")) { string num = plainText.Replace("i", "1111."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("I")) { string num = plainText.Replace("I", "000011."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("j")) { string num = plainText.Replace("j", "03."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("J")) { string num = plainText.Replace("J", "30."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("k")) { string num = plainText.Replace("k", "003."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("K")) { string num = plainText.Replace("K", "030."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("l")) { string num = plainText.Replace("l", "330."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("L")) { string num = plainText.Replace("L", "003."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("m")) { string num = plainText.Replace("m", "333."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("M")) { string num = plainText.Replace("M", "0030."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("n")) { string num = plainText.Replace("n", "30300."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("N")) { string num = plainText.Replace("N", "30330."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("o")) { string num = plainText.Replace("o", "33033."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("O")) { string num = plainText.Replace("O", "303033."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("p")) { string num = plainText.Replace("p", "30033."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("P")) { string num = plainText.Replace("P", "33003."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("q")) { string num = plainText.Replace("q", "13."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("Q")) { string num = plainText.Replace("Q", "31."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("r")) { string num = plainText.Replace("r", "1131."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("R")) { string num = plainText.Replace("R", "33113."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("s")) { string num = plainText.Replace("s", "31313."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("S")) { string num = plainText.Replace("S", "7."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("t")) { string num = plainText.Replace("t", "7331."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("T")) { string num = plainText.Replace("T", "1337."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("u")) { string num = plainText.Replace("u", "37."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("U")) { string num = plainText.Replace("U", "17."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("v")) { string num = plainText.Replace("v", "70."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("V")) { string num = plainText.Replace("V", "07."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("w")) { string num = plainText.Replace("w", "701."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("W")) { string num = plainText.Replace("W", "107."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("x")) { string num = plainText.Replace("x", "037."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("X")) { string num = plainText.Replace("X", "3307."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("y")) { string num = plainText.Replace("y", "11773."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("Y")) { string num = plainText.Replace("Y", "1073."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("z")) { string num = plainText.Replace("z", "7771."); plainText = num; };
    if (plainText.Contains("Z")) { string num = plainText.Replace("Z", "33107."); plainText = num; };

        // Add Branding
        string fplainText = "CC-ENC|" + plainText;
        return fplainText;
}
public static string CCDEC(string encryptedText)
{
    // Remove Branding
    if (encryptedText.Contains("CC-ENC|")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("CC-ENC|", ""); encryptedText = num; };
    // Decrypt Lowercase and Captial Letters
    if (encryptedText.Contains("01.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("01.", "a"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("11010.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("11010.", "A"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("10.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("10.", "b"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("110.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("110.", "B"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("1.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("1.", "c"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("0.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("0.", "C"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("11.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("11.", "d"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("00.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("00.", "D"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("010.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("010.", "e"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("001.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("001.", "E"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("1100.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("1100.", "f"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("0011.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("0011.", "F"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("00001.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("00001.", "g"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("01010.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("01010.", "G"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("110011.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("110011.", "h"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("110110.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("110110.", "H"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("1111.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("1111.", "i"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("000011.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("000011.", "I"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("03.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("03.", "j"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("30.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("30.", "J"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("003.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("003.", "k"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("030.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("030.", "K"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("330.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("330.", "l"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("003.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("003.", "L"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("333.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("333.", "m"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("0030.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("0030.", "M"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("30300.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("30300.", "n"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("30330.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("30330.", "N"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("33033.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("33033.", "o"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("303033.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("303033.", "O"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("30033.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("30033.", "p"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("33003.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("33003.", "P"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("13.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("13.", "q"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("31.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("31.", "Q"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("1131.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("1131.", "r"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("33113.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("33113.", "R"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("31313.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("31313.", "s"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("7.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("7.", "S"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("7331.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("7331.", "t"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("1337.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("1337.", "T"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("37.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("37.", "u"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("17.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("17.", "U"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("70.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("70.", "v"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("07.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("07.", "V"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("701.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("701.", "w"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("107.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("107.", "W"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("037.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("037.", "x"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("3307.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("3307.", "X"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("11773.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("11773.", "y"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("1073.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("1073.", "Y"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("7771.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("7771.", "z"); encryptedText = num; };
    if (encryptedText.Contains("33107.")) { string num = encryptedText.Replace("33107.", "Z"); encryptedText = num; };

    return encryptedText;
}
```

Comment: The most important thing for you to study is [how to use a debugger](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/).

Comment: Your code will be easier to read (and write) if you replace each line like `if (plainText.Contains("a")) { string num = plainText.Replace("a", "01."); plainText = num; };` with the equivalent statement `plainText = plainText.Replace("a", "01.");` As a bonus, this approach is also more efficient. You can also chain calls to `Replace`, as in `plainText = plainText.Replace("a", "01.").Replace("b", "10.");` and so on. But creating a collection of your substitutions, as suggested elsewhere, is indeed the far better approach. Not only is it easier to implement but it is also easier to improve.

Comment: @Echox, is any update? Please check if the following answers work for you.

Answer (score 3):

Your decryption is ambigous ...

Consider your example `01.10.1.11.`

If you look at your decryption method, you have a bunch of `if`s that are executed from top to bottom.

```
if (encryptedText.Contains("01.")) // replace with a
...  => encryptedText = "a10.1.11."
if (encryptedText.Contains("10.")) // replace with b
... => encryptedText = "ab1.11."
if (encryptedText.Contains("1.")) //replace with c
```

So what happens in this last line? In your string `ab1.11.` it replaces every instance of `1.` with c, leading to `abc1c` ie, the result you are seeing.

So for your encryption scheme to work, you have to make sure, that shorter substituions are not part of longer ones, or at least that the longer ones are checked earlier ... This is only one example of ambiguity. Other ones are for instance

```
q - R - S
r - T
V - W - X - Z
```

and many others too.

Furthermore, if you really want to build an encryption scheme with a substituion table (see below, why this isn't such a good idea), you can make your life a lot easier if you put your substition table in some sort of collection and just iterate over that collection instead of writing such a cascade of `if` conditions

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    static (string, string)[] substitutions = new(string, string)[] {
        ("a", "10."),
        ("b", "11."),
        ("c", "1."),
        ...
    };  
    
    static string encrypt(string plain) {
        var encrypted = plain;
        foreach (var s in substitutions) {
            encrypted = encrypted.Replace(s.Item1, s.Item2);
        }
        
        return encrypted;
    }
    
    static string decrypt(string encrypted) {
        var plain = encrypted;
        foreach (var s in substitutions) {
            plain = plain.Replace(s.Item2, s.Item1);
        }
        
        return plain;
    }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        var plain = "abc";
        var encrypted = encrypt(plain);
        var plain2 =decrypt(encrypted);
        Console.WriteLine(plain);
        Console.WriteLine(encrypted);
        Console.WriteLine(plain2);
    
    }
}
```

Regarding security: Simple subsitution ciphers are very weak encryptions, because most languages have a well known distribution of their characters, so if a character is always replaced with the same number, it's quite easy to guess which number encodes which character ... I strongly discourage using such a cipher -- even if implemented correctly -- in any environment where security is of some relevance. Please use well established and well designed encryption standards ...

Comment: Just to re-iterate one of @derpirscher 's points. Please do not use substitution ciphers for anything but academic purposes. Self-implemented cryptography algorithms, especially ones with weak cryptographic complexity,  are not recommended for any use other than hobby and education.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, I reproduced your problem. I don't recommend that you use string.replace and string.contains method to get the result because the code will still replace data `1.` in the `11.`.

Here is a code example you can refer to, which may solve this problem.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str1 = "CC-ENC|11010.01.10.1.11.";
            string str2 = "Aabcd";
            string m = CCENC(str2);
            Console.WriteLine(m);
            string n = CCDEC(str1);
            Console.WriteLine(n);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public static string CCDEC(string encryptedText)
        {
            // Remove Branding
            string num = "";
            if (encryptedText.Contains("CC-ENC|")) { num = encryptedText.Replace("CC-ENC|", ""); encryptedText = num; };
            string[] arr = num.Split('.');
            string result = "";
            foreach (var item in arr)
            {
                switch (item)
                {
                    case "01":
                        result = result + "a";
                        break;
                    case "10":
                        result = result + "b";
                        break;
                    case "1":
                        result = result + "c";
                        break;
                    case "11":
                        result = result + "d";
                        break;
                    case "11010":
                        result = result + "A";
                        break;
                        .
                        .
                        .
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("other case");
                        break;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
        public static string CCENC(string plainText)
        {
            string[] arr = plainText.Select(i=>i.ToString()).ToArray();
            string result = "";
            foreach (var item in arr)
            {
                switch (item)
                {
                    case "a":
                        result = result + "01.";
                        break;
                    case "b":
                        result = result + "10.";
                        break;
                    case "c":
                        result = result + "1.";
                        break;
                    case "d":
                        result = result + "11.";
                        break;
                    case "A":
                        result = result + "11010.";
                        break;
                        .
                        .
                        .
                    default:
                        
                        break;
                }
            }
            // Add Branding
            string fplainText = "CC-ENC|" + result;
            return fplainText;
        }
```

Besides, if you have two many conditions, I suggest that you can try to use `switch...case` sentence.
Result:

[image]